# Firebase Cloud Message Subscribe a Topic Web Push Notification

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM to send web push notifications, but I don't know how I can subscribe a Client to a specific topic using javascript.
Can anyone help me with this please?
I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 5.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible as far as I know. Topic subscriptions is supported natively by Android and iOS, but not for the Web.

You would need to manually implement it by:

1. User consents to "subscribe" to topic.
2. User Firebase token is stored in a database for the above topic.
3. Query database for all Firebase tokens associated with a given topic.
4. Send message to all users from above query.

You would then use:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#onMessage

Comment: Hi Francisco. Steps are good. Step 2 is strongly suggested to be done, but not a solid requirement -- just if you have to keep track of the tokens. For step 3, if step 2 wasn't done, devs could just use the [`batchAdd`](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_relationship_maps_for_app_instances) API to subscribe the token(s), by then step 4 should just be sending messages from their app server specifying the topic name (no need to query for the tokens). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Francisco and for the explication, @AL. Do you know how to get the User Firebase Token? I've tried with the methods in the documentation but doesn't work.

Comment: Use https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onIdTokenChanged